# How to create correct VB.NET object from json from Eurostat database

Tags: json, vb.net

I want to create VB.NET object to handle correctly json response from Eurostat database. The link that retrieves json string is http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/wdds/rest/data/v2.1/json/en/nama_10_gdp?geo=EU28&precision=1&na_item=B1GQ&unit=CP_MEUR&sinceTimePeriod=2010

How to use key value with vb.net object, below?
 "value": {
    "0": 12841530.5,
    "1": 13217461.4,
    "2": 13484170.7,
    "3": 13596777.6,
    "4": 14072023.3,
    "5": 14828635.5,
    "6": 14958292.3,
    "7": 15382357.6,
    "8": 15869095.6
  },

Comment: Hi. You want to show us what you have done so far in terms for coding and we can help you overcome a problem you encounter while implementing your functionality.

Comment: Public Class Value
    Public Property v0 As Double
    Public Property v1 As Double
End Class
The Class Value does not catch the values. EUData.value.v1 for example shows 0

Answer (score 0):

Create a class via jsonutils. For the example in subject:

```
Public Class Extension
    Public Property datasetId As String
    Public Property lang As String
    Public Property description As Object
    Public Property subTitle As Object
End Class

Public Class Value
    Public Property 0 As Double
    Public Property 1 As Double
    Public Property 2 As Double
    Public Property 3 As Double
    Public Property 4 As Double
    Public Property 5 As Double
    Public Property 6 As Double
    Public Property 7 As Double
    Public Property 8 As Double
End Class

Public Class Index
    Public Property CP_MEUR As Integer
End Class

Public Class Label
    Public Property CP_MEUR As String
End Class

Public Class Category
    Public Property index As Index
    Public Property label As Label
End Class

Public Class Unit
    Public Property label As String
    Public Property category As Category
End Class

Public Class NaItem
    Public Property label As String
    Public Property category As 
End Class

Public Class Geo
    Public Property label As String
    Public Property category As 
End Class

Public Class Time
    Public Property label As String
    Public Property category As 
End Class

Public Class Dimension
    Public Property unit As Unit
    Public Property na_item As NaItem
    Public Property geo As Geo
    Public Property time As Time
End Class

Public Class Example
    Public Property version As String
    Public Property label As String
    Public Property href As String
    Public Property source As String
    Public Property updated As String
    Public Property extension As Extension
    Public Property class As String
    Public Property value As Value
    Public Property dimension As Dimension
    Public Property id As String()
    Public Property size As Integer()
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro. The VB.NET does not accept 0, 1, 2 as names in Public Class Value. How to refer to "0", "1", ... ,"9" to get the values that json keeps?

Comment: Value is a `Dictionary(Of String, Double)`. Some other cathegories must be treated the same way.

Comment: Then, `unit`, `na_item`, `geo` and `time` are a single Class type that has two properties: `Label As String` and `Category As CategoryCommon`, where `CategoryCommon` is a class with Properties: `Index As Dictionary(Of String, Long) ` and `Label As Dictionary(Of String, String)`. Id is a `List(Of String)` and Size is a `List(Of Long)`.

Comment: Hi again, In an Public Class Value I added the row Public Property vrednosti As Dictionary(Of String, Double). When I use in code EUData.value.vrednosti.Item("0") it throws NullException. I checked and Vrednosti is Nothing! Please, what to do more?